# Spring boot form wizard

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a Spring Boot application that will handle multi page forms based on user input.

So, the flow might be different based on user selection.

Something like this:

User selects `Flow A --> FormA1, FormA2, FormA3, FormA4, Done`

User selects `Flow B --> FormB1, FormB2, FormB3, Done`

As you can see, the shared step among these flows might only be the last (success) part, apart from it all the forms, validations etc. will be specific to flow.

My question is, can I write a `WizardController` that will accept a list of forms, maybe validators for each step, a post process method for each step, a single template for rendering each step (or a different list of templates for each step) so I can generalise this pattern?

Something along these lines:

```
@Controller
public class WizardController {
    // This will hold list of form for each step
    private List<Form> formList;
    // A generalised template for each step
    private String template;

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        // This will only render the initial form
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String post() {
        // All POST requests will be handled here
        // If validation fails render current step, else next step or done
    }
}
```

So instead of creating a controller for each flow, I use the same `WizardController`. Does it sound over-engineering? How do achieve injecting `formList` into my controller? Do I need a `BeanFactory` in order to achieve this? (As form objects will be different each time. I'm quite new to Spring in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The WizardController should not contain any internal state (like the list of forms).

I'd recommend creating a service that can give you the form to render based on the current user (retrieved e.g. from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`) and the previous form.

```
@Service
public class FormService { /* ... */ }
```

This service can then be injected into the controller:

```
@Controller
public class WizardController {

    @Autowired
    private FormService formService;

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        formService.getInitialForm();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String post(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // find out which was the last form from
        // some request parameter

        formService.getNextForm(prevForm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can use session to store which flow to be generated for anonymous users as well? What is the best place to store the definition of flows and their related forms then?

Comment: There is no "best place" I guess. You could keep it in session or save it in a database (with session ID, as you don't have a user ID for guests). I'd probably prefer a database because this will be easier to debug.